# Flutter: Expanded overriding ConstrainedBox

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a `Column` to expand to a constrained width. So it expands until the `maxWidth` but doesn't mind being smaller if there isn't enough space. But the `Expanded` ignores the `ConstrainedBox`.

```
    Row(
      children: [
        const Spacer(),
        Expanded(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 50),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Here's my full code for context:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GetBuilder<TimerController>(
          builder: (_) => CustomBackground(
            color: _timerController.currentChild?.color ?? Colors.blue,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppSizes.pagePadding),
                  child: OrientationBuilder(
                    builder: (context, orientation) =>
                        (orientation == Orientation.portrait)
                            ? ConstrainedBox(
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: AppSizes.maxWidth,
                                  minWidth: AppSizes.minWidth,
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(height: AppSizes.pagePadding),
                                    Expanded(child: TimerClock()),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          NameText(),
                                          ControlButtons(),
                                          SizedBox(height: 25),
                                          Expanded(child: QueueList()),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            : Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                        maxWidth: AppSizes.maxWidth,
                                        minWidth: AppSizes.minWidth,
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: AppSizes.pagePadding),
                                        child: TimerClock(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: AppSizes.pagePadding),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                        maxWidth: AppSizes.maxWidth,  // this get's ignored
                                        minWidth: AppSizes.minWidth,
                                      ),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(child: NameText()),
                                          ControlButtons(),
                                          SizedBox(height: 25),
                                          Expanded(child: QueueList()),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And if I remove the `Expanded`, the `Column` has a fixed width (`maxWidth`) and throws an error if there isn't enough space.

Answer (score 11):

Change the outer most `Expanded` to a `Flexible`. Then the child `ConstrainedBox` will be respected.

In my case I also added a `width:double.infinity` to the child of the `Flexible` to force the widget to always be as big as the maxWidth, and only reduce its size when there is no space.

My example:

```
Flexible(
  child: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: screenWidth * 0.25),
    width: double.infinity,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Expanded` in a `Column` widget which means that it will try to expand to fill the space vertically (based on the height of the parent not its width). As mentioned in the documentation of `Expanded`:

> Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex
> expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g.,
> **horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column**).

[source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

And as you did not precise a `maxHeight` in your constraints it will be considered as `double.infinity`.

Comment: but I'm using the `Expanded` in a `Row` so it should fill the space horizontally. The `Column` is in the `Expanded` to expand horizontally and the `ConstrainedBox` should limit the amount the `Column` can expand.

Comment: Then it might be related to your `Row` missing some constraints in your layout. I've tested your sample in a new DartPad and it works correctly. Here's the code: https://dartpad.dev/?id=1c4544ae6935924dc9ddc6338dddf049&null_safety=true
To help you better you will have to post a full reproducible example based on your code.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the full code now. Maybe it will help

Comment: "I've tested your sample in a new DartPad and it works correctly": it doesn't, set the `maxWidth` to `50` and the `Column` will still cover half the screen